The callback processing function in the telebot does not work
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def main(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    buy_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Buy",
                                             callback_data="buy")
    purchases_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Purchases",
                                               callback_data="show_purchases")

    markup.row(buy_btn, purchases_btn)

    settings_btn = types.InlineKeyboardButton("Settings",
                                              callback_data="show_settings")
    markup.row(settings_btn)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Choose one:", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def callbacks(callback):
    print(f"Callback data received: {callback.data}")
    if callback.data == "buy":
        bot.send_message(callback.message.chat.id, "Buy")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)

I have several buttons that are supposed to do something. I'm trying to handle a callback in a separate callback function. But when I click on the button, no callback seems to come. The function does not work under any conditions, it does not output anything, no matter what button I press.
I'm learning telebot from tutorial videos and have tried to double-check my code several times. All conditions for work have been met. I looked at the official documentation about callback processing, but it was the same.
I expect that the callbacks function will at least print out at least some of the received callbacks.
